# Time search function is not working properly in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying add a time search to my PHP site, which already has a date search and it is working fine.But when I tried to add time search it is not working properly.It seems like it is sending the data but doesn't effect much.

For example when I choose 13:00 as start time
and 16:00 as a end time ,it shows all the records from those days ,doesn't care about the time.But if I choose same time for both start and end ,it shows nothing.And same for choosing a time higher than end time for start time, shows nothing again.

```
//search_model.php
if(!empty($data['start'])){
$this->db->where('Date(requests.confirmed_at) >=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['start'])));
}
if(!empty($data['end'])){
$this->db->where('Date(requests.confirmed_at) <=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['end'])));
}
if(!empty($data['starttime'])){
$this->db->where('Date(requests.confirmed_at) >=', date("H:i", strtotime($data['starttime'])));
}
if(!empty($data['endtime'])){
$this->db->where('Date(requests.confirmed_at) <=', date("H:i", strtotime($data['endtime'])));
}


//search_view.php
<div class="form-group" id="data_5">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label font-normal"><?php echo lang('select_date_range');?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" name="start" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>"/>

<div class="input-group clockpicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="starttime" id="starttime">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
</span>
</div>


<span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" name="end" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" />

<div class="input-group clockpicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="endtime" id="endtime">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

Have no problems with posting the data between view to model.So I think it is about model but I couldn't
sort it out.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the "Date" function will return only the Date of a date time string, so `Date('2019-08-24 10:29:00')` would return "2019-08-24".

Looking at your code, the first two blocks are looking at the date, against the date. The next two blocks are looking at time against date, this is where the issue lies.

For reference please see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html (note this is for MySQL 5.7, make sure to reference the doc from the version you are using).

In this case above, if you don't require a date constraint when filtering your data by time, you can use the TIME() function  from the documentation above.